# Contextual filter that checks front page URL for taxonomy term

Tags: views, 7

My site is laid out in the following way using the [Sites Module](https://drupal.org/project/sites):

mysite.com/one
mysite.com/two
mysite.com/three

(And so on)

Additionally, there are subpages created with [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) for each of these "Sites" such as:

mysite.com/one/content
mysite.com/two/content
mysite.com/three/content

etc.

I share a single view (generated as a block) on these pages that displays content from a content type based on the taxonomy term found in the URL using Contextual Filters in the view. The taxonomy terms assigned to the content, in this case, are "one" "two" "three" etc.

The view block works as intended on the page with a contextual filter of "*filter not avail default -> raw url -> path component 1 -> use path alias* and *filter is avail -> specify criteria -> validator taxonomy term -> term name converted to id -> transform dashes*" **IF** the taxonomy term appears in the URL **after** the main "sites" page in the path (in this case /one).

This means the view block at mysite.com/one does **not** work, but mysite.com/one/one **does**.

Also, mysite.com/one/one/content filters correctly, as does mysite.com/one/one/one/content etc.

I need the contextual filter to consider the "site" name (as determined by Sites or just by the URL that the user enters) in the URL when determining the taxonomy term to filter by.